# How to get the affected rows in sql from php

Tags: php, android, mysqli

I have written down the following code..But when I try to get the affected rows (to check if the user details matches the database's) it ALWAYS return 0 as affected rows even if the statement is executed successfully..What have I done wrong?

```
if($connection){

$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";

$statement = mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT * FROM  `admin` WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1){
    $response = array('response'=>true);
}else{
    $response = array('response'=>false);
}

echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($connection);     }
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass the `$connection` variable to the function but the result. Instead of using `mysqli_affected_rows` you might use `mysqli_num_rows` it might become confusing in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [mysqli_stmt_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) function, that takes a statement as the parameter:

Change

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1)
```

to

```
if(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) != 0)
```

Comment: Im getting the data from the $statement variable above..right?

Comment: Look, try `echo`ing the value of `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)` & see whether it's equal to **0** or not. If it is **0**, then that means that your `SELECT` query does not return any rows.

Comment: It returns -1 in both cases..I think that matters that I bind the params and the statement it self has "?" in it..

Comment: The function returns `-1` means that your query encountered an error; debug it

Comment: I'm sorry I can't debug it for you. There could be a lot of problematic things, & I can't tell them based on what you have posted so far; you gonna have to do it yourself : at least, now you know what the problem is, **your query**.